# Add a noise texture to a weight paint?

Tags: texturing, vertices, weight-painting

Is there perhaps a way to add a noise texture to the weight paint? I am scattering assets with geometry nodes and want them to appear in different places via the weight map (redder means more density), but I want to add a texture instead of painting the weight. Is there a way to do this?

(Image: This is what I've been doing. I want to find a way to add a texture instead of painting it.)

[image]

Comment: As well as [MVB's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260408/35559), you could use a texture directly inside the scattering GN group, to control instance density or any other attribute, without going via vertex-weights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Geometry Nodes

You can modify the vertex group using a texture in Geometry nodes (you can use image textures too there):

[image]

**An example with an image texture**

[image]

Comment: I edited my post with new info.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 make the geometry nodes setup I presented above and apply the modifier.

Comment: See my question again, please.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 You didn't modify it since the last time I looked at it... If you replicate my setup and go to weight paint mode, you will see the colors change, because the weight information is changed by geonodes.

Comment: I meant that in the weight painting window, I want to add a texture png from Photoshop into the weight paint, not procedurally with geo nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That's just what I needed!